# Listview throws exception when I try to set DataSource

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, webforms, model-binding

I have a ListView which displays fine. However, when I try and set the `DataSource` programmatically it throws this error:

```
DataSource or DataSourceID cannot be defined on 'ListView1' when it uses model binding.
```

This is how my button code looks:

```
protected void btSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string searchValue = tbSearch.Text;
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
  {
    using (WalkContext db = new WalkContext())
    {          
      var query = (from w in db.DogWalks.Include("Pictures")
                   where w.Title.Contains(searchValue)
                   select w);

        ListView1.DataSource = query;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is a snippet from my `ListView`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="WalkID" ItemType="DogWalks.DAL.DogWalk" SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData">
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" class="img-responsive pull-left" style="min-width:262.5px;min-height:150px;" runat="server" ImageUrl=<%# Item.Pictures.FirstOrDefault().PictureUrl %>/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <a href="/Walks/WalkDetails?WalkID=<%#Item.WalkID%>">
         <h3><b><%# Item.Title%></b></h3>
      </a>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I can see in debugger that the query is returning the correct number of results, I just can't seem to get the Listview to accept the query. I have also tried adding `.toList()` but this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You can't set `DataSource` when using [Model Binding](http://blog.pluralsight.com/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-model-binding) (`SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData"` in your view).
You need to move the query logic from 'btSearch_Click' to `ListView1_GetData` method